# Problema ao Editar Registro no Delphhi

Tags: mysql, delphi

Boa noite pessoal! Entrei recentemente no mundo Delphi e criei algumas aplicações para cadastro de clientes usando o banco MySQL. Os registros adicionados ao banco são mostrados em um DBGrid e ao dar um duplo click em cima do registro, abre a página do PageControl onde é realizado o cadastro, exclusão e edição dos dados. Até ai tudo bem, porém ao clicar no botão para editar o registro, todos os DBEdits da página de cadastro mudam para o último cadastro feito no sistema. Alguém saberia me auxiliar a resolver esse erro?

Click do DBGrid:

`procedure TFrmUsuarios.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dm.tb_Usuarios.Active := True;
  dm.tb_Usuarios.Edit;
  txt_Nome.Text := dm.sql_con_usuariosnome.Value;
  txt_Id.Text   := IntToStr (dm.sql_con_usuariosid.Value);
  txt_Senha.Text:= dm.sql_con_usuariossenha.Value;
  ChamarDetalhes;
  ConfigBotoes;
  HabilitarCampos;
end;`

Click do botão Edit:

`procedure TFrmUsuarios.btn_alterarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dm.tb_Usuarios.Active := True;
  dm.tb_Usuarios.Edit;
  ChamarDetalhes;
  ConfigBotoes;
  HabilitarCampos;
end;`

Desde Já Agradeço!!

Comment: Precisamos saber o que fazem estes métodos: ChamarDetalhes, ConfigBotoes e HabilitarCampos.

Comment: Há algumas inconsistências entre o código que você mostrou e o que escreveu. O DataSource da sua DBGrid está ligado a qual componente de dados (TTable ou TQuery)? Você falou sobre os DBEdit, mas seu código refere-se a TEdit (`txt_Nome.Text`). Esse `dm.sql_con_usuariosnome.Value` é um TField? se sim, de qual TTable?

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite amigo, pelo uma boa prática é tu informar o

> first

do teu componente de data, fazendo assim:

```
procedure TFrmUsuarios.btn_alterarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dm.tb_Usuarios.Active := True;
  dm.tb_Usuarios.First;
  dm.tb_Usuarios.Edit;
  ChamarDetalhes;
  ConfigBotoes;
  HabilitarCampos;
end;
```

Caso você queira utilizar o registro selecionado, é só usar o

> Filter.

```
dm.tb_Usuarios.Filtered := False;
dm.tb_Usuarios.Filter   := 'CAMPO_CHAVE = ' + IntToStr(dm.sql_con_usuariosid.AsInteger);
dm.tb_Usuarios.Filtered := True;
```

Espero que ajude. Abraço